# Azure Durable Functions - 401 Unauthorized Status

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have developed a Hello World Durable Function using the Sample Code provided by Azure function Team.

Everything was working fine until sometime back. All of sudden I'm getting 401 Unauthorized status code when I try to check the status of my Hello World Durable Function program.

Below is the URL https://exploredurablefunctions.azurewebsites.net/admin/extensions/DurableTaskConfiguration/instances/1819db89e68e42f1a2240d532e20eb77?taskHub=DurableFunctionsHub&connection=Storage

Surprisingly, I don't see any error in the Table Storage.

[image]

Below are the Instance ID and Execution Ids
{"InstanceId":"1819db89e68e42f1a2240d532e20eb77","ExecutionId":"81607af286b744ba80a303d74ed6b624"}

Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A recent Azure Functions update broke the built-in HTTP APIs in Durable Functions, including the status query API. More details here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1754

An update to the Durable Functions extension is coming soon which will fix the issue. Until then, you can resolve the issue by pointing your function app to an earlier version of the Azure Functions runtime - e.g. setting the `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` app setting to `1.0.11027`.

Comment: Thank you so much Chris. It's working now after changing the version!

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm now running into another problem. The status is always "running". However, the history logs in the Table Storage says, Orchestraion Complete and Task Completed.

Comment: I have created Manual Triggers for Orchestration Trigger and Activity Trigger and replaced both the run.csx and the function.json with that of E1_HelloSequence and E1_SayHello, I can see only the following statusus in the table Storage OrchestrationStarted, OrchestrationCompleted, TaskScheduled, ExecutionStarted and the status is always running. However, when I upload E1_HelloSequence and E1_SayHello folders (provided by Azure Team) via Kudu, it's working as expected. Looks wierd!

Comment: aah, Now, I got it. The Activity Function name that I mentioned was incorrect! There should be some way where one can understand that there is no such Function!

Comment: Yep, I agree. I opened a bug to track this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/24